# JFontChooser remove preview panel or force maximum size

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a [`JFontChooser`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfontchooser/) to pick a font for a text area. I've added to the font chooser a `JPanel` which is placed above another `JPanel` containing the text area. The problem is, that if the font size gets too big, the preview window part of the font chooser resizes the entire thing, taking up space. I've tried forcing a maximum size on the panel containing the font chooser, but to no avail.

The `topPanel` contains the font chooser and a button; the `midPanel` contains the `textArea`.

```
public TextEditorWindow(IConnector connect, FolderSearchComp fs, GuiConstructor gui, LoopControlWindow loopc) {
    this.connect = connect;
    this.fs = fs;
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    this.gui = gui;
    font = fs.getFormatFont();
    this.loopc = loopc;
    initComps();
    size = new Dimension(610, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - 100);
}

private void createTopPanel() {
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    applyButton = new JButton("Apply Font");
    applyButton.addActionListener(this);
    applyButton.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

    fc = new JFontChooser();
    fc.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    fc.setSelectedFont(font);

    topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a font"));
    topPanel.add(fc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topPanel.add(applyButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    topPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,300));

}

 private void createMidPanel() {
    midPanel = new JPanel();
    midPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    textArea = new JTextArea(20,20);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    scroll.setViewportView(textArea);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    midPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Here is a picture of the default font size I need for the application.

[image: first]

and here it is with a very big font size.

[image: second]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Note: to make an MCVE of this problem that most people can run, it will be necessary to factor out the 3rd party API that seems the major component in this problem. Try replacing it with a text area that has the number of columns and rows set, and a font size that can change.  The root of the problem is probably in the use of layouts.